# How to Scrape a web-page into a dictionary compatible with Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: html, pandas, dataframe

```
from collections import defaultdict
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import pandas as pd

r= requests.get("http://www.walmart.com/search/?query=marvel&cat_id=4096_530598")
r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class" : "tile-content"})
g_price = soup.find_all("div",{"class" : "item-price-container"})
g_star = soup.find_all("div",{"class" : "stars stars-small tile-row"})

data=defaultdict(list)
for product_title in g_data:
    a_product_title = product_title.find_all("a","js-product-title")
    for text_product_title in a_product_title : 
       data['Product Title'].append(textroduct_title.text)  

for row in g_price:
    price = row.find('span', 'price price-display').text.strip()
    data['Price'].append(price)

for allstar in g_star:
    star=allstar.find('span','visuallyhidden').text.stp()
    data['Stars'].append(star)

dd_starring = soup.find_all('dd', {"class" : "media-details-artist-dd module"})
for dd in dd_starring :
     actors = dd.text
 #data['Actors'].append(actors)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

[image: output of stars (without the line - data['Stars'].append(star)][image: output of appending product title and price to df]

---

if I add to try to append it using the line `data['Stars'].append(star)` - I get the following error--

> ValueError: arrays must all be the same length

What should be done to append it and the rows that don't have a star should have NA in it.

Any suggestions? please help

Comment: The problem is that the HTML you're accessing only has 15 star categories while the other attributes have 20 values to iterate on. You should try to structure one loop through the HTML and add "" or NaN values to your data['stars'] array on each loop.

Comment: yes. data frame only takes list of same length.  I was trying to declare a list of default value NaN then add contents to others and append.    Thanks for looking into the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to build individual lists of content to loop through. You can just iterate through g_data, and this means you won't have different length result sets.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import pandas as pd

r= requests.get("http://www.walmart.com/search/?query=marvel&cat_id=4096_530598")
r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class" : "tile-content"})

data=defaultdict(list)
for content in g_data:
    title = content.find("a","js-product-title")
    data['Product Title'].append(title.text)

    try:
        stars =content.find("div",{"class" : "stars stars-small tile-row"}).find('span','visuallyhidden').text.strip()
        data['Stars'].append(stars)

    except:
        data['Stars'].append(None)

    price = content.find('span', 'price price-display').text.strip()
    data['Price'].append(price)



 #data['Actors'].append(actors)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

As far as I could see the inner loops were also not necessary as each item only has one name, price and rating.

Comment: ohh.. a friend of mine suggested to declare  a list... add default values of NaN to it and add content.  But this is also a good idea. :) thank you

Comment: In your original method that wouldn't work, at least if I understand you correctly, because you wouldn't have accounted for the position of the NaN values

Answer (score 0):

Your original issue was caused because your individual loops did not contain the same amount of each element you were looping through (i.e. - 15 stars, v. 20 prices). The best way to avoid this type of issue is to firstly have one loop and then to apply a try & except value to each item you're scaping. That way if there are any issues with the constant presence of the items you want, you can still collect what is present.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import pandas as pd

r= requests.get("http://www.walmart.com/search/?query=marvel&cat_id=4096_530598")
r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class" : "tile-content"})

data=defaultdict(list)

#One loop to rule them all
for tile in g_data:
    #the "tile" value in g_data contains what you are looking for...
    #find the product titles
    try:
        title = tile.find("a","js-product-title")
        data['Product Title'].append(title.text)
    except:
        data['Product Title'].append("")

    #find the prices
    try:
        price = tile.find('span', 'price price-display').text.strip()
        data['Price'].append(price)  
    except:
        data['Price'].append("")

    #find the stars
    try:
        g_star = tile.find("div",{"class" : "stars stars-small tile-row"}).find('span','visuallyhidden').text.strip()
        data['Stars'].append(g_star)
    except:
        data['Stars'].append("")

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: ya.. You are right . This a very robust way of coding. Thank you.